# IF formula with multiple conditions and outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, nested-if

I try to create IF formula to give me 3 different outcomes based on number in two cells (e.g. A1 and B1).

The 3 outcomes are:

- "NO CHANGE" if A1 or B1 is equal to zero,
- "CHANGE BELOW THRESHOLD" if A1 or B1 value is different than zero but below 10,000 and above -10,000,
- "CHANGE" if A1 or B1 value is above 10,0000 or below -10,000.

I managed to create formula =IF(OR(A1<>0,B1<>0,"CHANGE","NO CHANGE")), howeveri I cannot find logic to test more conditions and give me 3 different results. Maybe I should try IFS?

I'd be really grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, if you want to consider different conditions `IFS` would be the option. If you have nested conditions, then to use nested `IF` conditions. Check your formula you have misplaced the closing parenthesis of the `OR`.

Comment: Is the Excel-2010 tag accurate? If so, `IFS()` is not even an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may need to be adjusted as your current description has a lot of "OR" statements but doesn't really specify how you would treat occasions where Criteria 2 and 3 overlap (such as A1=5000 and B1=22000).

Here I'm stating that "no change" = both values must be between -10000 and 10000 (unless one of the values is 0).

Adjust the "=" as needed, depending how you want to classify 10000 and -10000.

If you have IFS:

```
=IFS(OR(A1=0,B1=0),"no change", AND(A1>-10000,A1<10000,B1>-10000,B1<10000),"change below threshold",OR(A1<=-10000,A1>=10000,B1<=-10000,B1>=10000),"change")
```

Using Nested IF:

```
=IF(OR(A1=0,B1=0),"no change", IF(AND(A1>-10000,A1<10000,B1>-10000,B1<10000),"change below threshold","change"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I want to get different results. 

In case if A1 or B2 is different than 0 then outcome should be "change below threshold" and if e.g. A1 is in range -9 999 to 9 999 but B2 exceeds 10 000 then it should be "Change".

Comment: But you wrote "OR" in `NO CHANGE" if A1 or B1 is equal to zero,`... so do you mean `and` instead? I answered the question as written. Change the first OR in the formula to AND if you want both A and B to be zero for "no change".

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, apologies for confusion. I've changed the first OR to AND and it made this formula work exactly as I needed. Thank you very much for your help and time!